# How to read a particular data format

Tags: python

What shold I use in python 3 to read Json format?

Comment: You have the data stored as a string in a `.txt` file ?

Comment: It looks like JSON, from there you should be able to figure it out...

Comment: yes it is JSON format

Comment: If you already knew that, why are you asking?

Comment: and I can not get particular value

Comment: what is the best method to read json format

Comment: With the `json` module, predictably enough. If you've had trouble with a particular value, then provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code and input data and precisely describe the problem with it.

Comment: from json import loads

with open("wall.txt", "r") as f:
    data = loads(f.read())
    print(data)

Comment: and I get ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 6019 column 1 (char 18470 - 27760213)

Comment: {"items": [{"date": 1430852956, "from_id": 142938951, "text": "", "id": 792533, "likes": {"user_likes": 0, "count": 0, "can_like": 1}},, {"date": 1430853029, "from_id": 157394803, "text": "А якщо переможець буде з Полтави наприклад,то що робити?"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in a some JSON data in a file:

```
from json import loads

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = loads(f.read())
```

To get the first date in "items":

```
first_date = date["items"][0]["date"]
```